# Command aliases in my script

Tags: linux, unix, bash

I am creating a script for copying files or directory with a date attached to its name, for example if the file name is `test` it will be `test-20130901.bkup`

and this is my script

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
set -x

getopts fd TYPE
[ $TYPE = "d" ] && alias cp="cp -r"

backup_error() {
        echo "${0##*/}: $1"
        exit -1
}

typeset -r FROM_DIR=$2 TO_DIR=$3
if [ ! -e $FROM_DIR -a ! -d $FROM_DIR ] || [ ! -e $TO_DIR -a ! -d $TO_DIR ]
then
        backup_error "One of the directories isn't exist or it maybe a file";
fi

typeset -r DATE=$(date "+%Y%m%d")
for filename in $FROM_DIR/*
do
        if [ -$TYPE $filename ]
        then
                cp $filename $TO_DIR/${filename##*/}-$DATE.bkup
        fi
done

unalias cp
```

In the script I check if the user wants to run the script on files only or on directories only.
`-f` for files only
`-d` for directories only

`[ $TYPE = "d" ] && alias cp="cp -r"`, this line to check if the script runs for directory I must use `cp -r` so I make an alias for `cp` to be `cp -r`

but when I use `set -x` to debug I find the when a user use `-d` option the `cp` command in the `if` still the original one not the alias.

Debugging:

```
> ./backup.sh -d . .
+ getopts fdb TYPE
+ '[' d = d ']'
+ alias 'cp=cp -r'
+ typeset -r FROM_DIR=. TO_DIR=.
+ '[' '!' -e . -a '!' -d . ']'
+ '[' '!' -e . -a '!' -d . ']'
++ date +%Y%m%d
+ typeset -r DATE=20130901
+ '[' -d ./backup.sh ']'
+ '[' -d ./dir1 ']'
+ cp ./dir1 ./dir1-20130901.bkup
cp: ./dir1: is a directory
+ '[' -d ./file1 ']'
+ '[' -d ./file2 ']'
+ '[' -d ./test.sh ']'
+ unalias cp
```

Comment: [ $TYPE = "d" ] && __cp="cp -r" || __cp="cp"

and then ....

$__cp $filename $TO_DIR/${filename##*/}-$DATE.bkup

just throw out the aliasing/unaliasing approach ))

Comment: This is fine, but do you know any justification for what happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a function instead:

```
if [[ $TYPE == d ]]; then
    function cp {
        command cp -r "$@"
    }
fi
```

And when in Bash, `[[ ]]` is recommended over `test` or `[ ]`.

Also quote please quote your variables properly between `""` to prevent word splitting and unexpected pathname expansion.

Other caveats:

```
    exit -1  ## exit can only accept 8-bit integral values from 0 to 255. -1 here is orthodox and is equivalent to 255.
```

You should quote the variables here or use `[[ ]]`:

```
    if [[ ! -e $FROM_DIR && ! -d $FROM_DIR ]] || [[ ! -e $TO_DIR && ! -d $TO_DIR ]]

    if [ "-$TYPE" "$filename" ]  ## for custom operators, test is better: test "-$TYPE" "$filename"

            cp "$filename" "$TO_DIR/${filename##*/}-$DATE.bkup"

for filename in "$FROM_DIR"/*
```

Lastly make sure you run your script as:

```
bash script.sh -f from_dir to_dir
# Or
bash script.sh -d from_dir to_dir
```

Comment: This is fine, but do you know any justification for what happened?

Comment: @M_E According to here: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html, *Aliases are not expanded when the shell is not interactive, unless the expand_aliases shell option is set using shopt*. And that's not only that: *aliases defined in a function are not available until after that function is executed. To be safe, always put alias definitions on a separate line, and do not use alias in compound commands.*

Comment: Somehow when inside a script or under a subshell aliases aren't expanded at all. It's somehow confusing and were also not sure if its implementation is stable or the same in every version of bash. This is the reason why functions are mostly preferred inside scripts and even in interactive environments.